# How to recommend items based on historical shopping basket contents

Tags: regression, logit, recommender-system, euclidean

Say you know the contents of shopping baskets many clients had at checkout. Based on this, you want to recommend an item to buy based on the item currently in the basket.

How would you do this?

Maybe enumerate the baskets and represent each item as a sparse vector showing which basket had the item been in, e.g. [1,0,0,1,0] meaning the item had been in the first and fourth basket only. Then calculate the inverted Euclidean distance of such vectors? Or perhaps the cosine distance instead as it is better for sparse vectors?

Or maybe by comparing each 2 items by representing them as a vector of numbers of occurrences in common baskets only, e.g. [2,1,4] and [1,1,3] meaning the two item have 3 baskets in common, where the first item occured twice in the first common basket, once in the second and 4 times in the third. Then the Euclidian distance of these vectors, weighed by the ratio of common basket to total number of baskets.

Maybe by multinominal logistic regression?

Maybe Jaccard similarity? I.e. X ∩ Y / X ∪ Y, where X is the number of baskets containing the first item and Y the number of baskets containing the second.

I feel this is a very simple and already solved problem, but my relevant knowledge has faded terribly.

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is [frequent item subsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning), i.e., find which items are bought together. If you dont have the item attributes I think it will be difficult to tell whether two items are 'similar' just based on shopping baskets.

Comment: Well, "similarity" might be a bad word choice. I'm trying to figure out what item are likely to go together for recommendation purposes, more than actually discover similarity. I changed the wording to reflect this. Looking into your link...